# About string split method in java

Tags: java, split, dot, strsplit, sentence

In java split method when we split the sentence by "." . Why we write "\." instead of "." ?? But when we split the sentence by comma we use only ",".

Comment: because it's a regex you pass, not a flat String. in a regex '.' is a special character

Comment: In addition to above comment, you can find the list of special characters in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: For all special characters we use " \\ "?

Comment: In regular expressions `,` matches `,` . `\\.` matches `.` . `.` matches any character because `.` is a special regex character meaning "any character". See [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: To keep it readable: `string.split(Pattern.quote("."))`.